# Proxmox 3.0 installation on any VPS

Tags: vps, kvm-virtualization, kernel, debian-wheezy, proxmox

I have an account on digitialocean.com
I create a droplet debian wheezy.
I installed proxmox 3.0 manually via command line.
At the end of installation I restarted the server but again it uses default kernel.
I want to use Proxmox customized kernel but I can't change.
Also I rewrite grub files but again nothing changed.

I wonder that is it possible to install proxmox on VPS or not?
If possible, how can I restart VPS with proxmox kernel (PVE)?
Thanks...

Comment: You can't run custom kernels on Digital Ocean. This is one of its most commonly noticed bugs and most commonly requested to be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

PROXMOX cannot be installed on a VPS. It also needs to be on installed on 3 servers for a cluster at minimum.